# Change settings on Samsung Galaxy tablet restricted profile

Tags: samsung, tablet, restricted-profiles

My kids have restricted profiles on my Samsung Galaxy tablet. The settings are good and I like the ability to control which apps they have access to. However, they are unable to sign in to their Google accounts on YouTube, as this appears to be a limitation of a Galaxy restricted profile. They already have Gmail accounts. Each time they try to sign in, they get an error message: "This change isn't permitted by your admin".

Since I am the admin, I would like to change this setting so that they can use their Gmail account to sign in to YouTube. Is there a way to access the settings to perform this change?

Thanks!